# Script BAT o CMD que descargue archivo y lo ejecute

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Necesito crear un `.bat` o `.cmd` que descargue de internet un archivo y tras la descarga lo ejecute, pero no sé si esto se puede y de ser posible que debería contener el archivo.

Inicié probando esto:

```
@echo off
START  "url=https://mipagina.com/descargas/actualizacion.exe"
```

Estuve leyendo un poco y lo cambié por esto:

```
@Echo OFF
SET "url=https://mipagina.com/descargas/actualizacion.exe"
SET "output=.\actualizacion.exe"
```

Pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué has probado a hacer? ¿Qué problemas tienes hasta ahora? Imagino que te no importa que salga la advertencia de seguridad de Windows, ¿no?.

Comment: cree el archivo con un @echo off e incluí un START con la url pero no funciona, no hace anda. Y no, no importa la advertencia

Comment: Es importante que muestres tus avances y con base a esto podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que te propuse? ¿Tienes alguna duda? Déjame un comentario si es así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [`bitsadmin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/bitsadmin-tool#__________Transfer__________name__________type___________priority_job_priority___________ACLFlags_flags__________remote_name_local_name________) para descargar un archivo y luego ejecutarlo con `start`:

```
@echo off

bitsadmin /transfer midescarga /download /priority normal ^
  "https://mipagina.com/descargas/actualizacion.exe" "%TEMP%\actualizacion.exe"

start "Actualización" "%TEMP%\actualizacion.exe"
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono a la perfección